# Using "lerna publish --conventional-commits" auto generate CHANGELOG.md with wrong commit link

Tags: lerna, changelog

I use `lerna publish --conventional-commits` to auto generate CHANGELOG.md. And lerna default use "conventional-changelog-angular" preset which generates the wrong commits link.

**lerna log**

```
lerna info getChangelogConfig Successfully resolved preset "conventional-changelog-angular"
```

**CHANGELOG.md**

```
## [0.19.224-alpha.0](wrong link) (2019-10-12)


### Bug Fixes

* commit message ([c5232fc](wrong link))
```

Has anyone run into the same problem or any idea how to solve it? Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Changing each workspace's package.json's `repository` to reference the root mono-repo URL solved this for me. This is described in the lerna issue #2299

Found [this lerna issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2299) that describes my issue.